# Need help, AVL Tree of objects

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

Our teacher provided us with the AVL_Tree.h and AVL_Node.h

I am trying to declare a new AVL_Tree of Folder (class that I created). However I keep getting the same error

```
 error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &,const 
 std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const 
 std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &' from 'const AVLNode<Item_Type>'
```

Here is the AVL_Tree class

```
 #ifndef AVL_TREE_H
 #define AVL_TREE_H


 #include "AVL_Node.h"

 template<typename Item_Type>
 class AVL_Tree{
 public:

AVL_Tree() : root(NULL){
}


AVL_Tree(const Item_Type& the_data, const AVL_Tree<Item_Type>& left_child = AVL_Tree(), 
    const AVL_Tree<Item_Type>& right_child = AVL_Tree()) :
    root(new AVLNode<Item_Type>(the_data, left_child.root,
    right_child.root)) {}

/** Return the left-subtree */
AVL_Tree<Item_Type> get_left_subtree() const {
        if (root == NULL) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("get_left_subtree on empty tree");
        }
        return AVL_Tree<Item_Type>(root->left);
}


/** Return the right-subtree */
AVL_Tree<Item_Type> get_right_subtree() const {
        if (root == NULL) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("get_right_subtree on null tree");
        }
        return AVL_Tree<Item_Type>(root->right);
    }

/** Return the data field of the root
@throws std::invalid_argument if null tree
*/

const Item_Type& AVL_Tree<Item_Type>::get_data() const {
    if (root == NULL) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("get_data on null tree");
    }
    return root->data;
}

bool is_null() const {
    return root == NULL;
}

/** Indicate that this tree is a leaf. */
bool is_leaf() const {
    if (root != NULL) {
        return root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL;
    }
    else
        return true;
}


virtual bool insert(const Item_Type& item) {
    return insert(this->root, item);
}

bool erase(const Item_Type& item) {
    return erase(this->root, item);
}

const Item_Type* find(const Item_Type& item) const {
    return find(this->root, item);
}




 protected:

AVLNode<Item_Type>* root;

AVL_Tree(AVLNode<Item_Type>* new_root) : root(new_root) {}

const Item_Type* find(AVLNode<Item_Type>* local_root, const Item_Type& target) const {
    if (local_root == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (target < local_root->data)
        return find(local_root->left, target);
    else if (local_root->data < target)
        return find(local_root->right, target);
    else
        return &(local_root->data);
}

bool erase(AVLNode<Item_Type>*& local_root, const Item_Type& item) {
    if (local_root == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if (item < local_root->data){
            bool return_value = erase(local_root->left, item);
            if (return_value){
                adjust_balance(local_root);
                rebalance(local_root);
            }
            return return_value;
        }
        else if (local_root->data < item){
            bool return_value = erase(local_root->right, item);
            if (return_value){
                adjust_balance(local_root);
                rebalance(local_root);
            }
            return return_value;
        }
        else {
            AVLNode<Item_Type>* old_root = local_root;

            if (local_root->left == NULL) 
                local_root = local_root->right;
            else if (local_root->right == NULL) 
                local_root = local_root->left;
            else 
                replace_parent(old_root, old_root->left);

            if (local_root != NULL){
                adjust_balance(local_root);
                rebalance(local_root);
            }

            delete old_root;
            return true;
        }
    }
}

void rebalance(AVLNode<Item_Type>*& local_root){
    if (local_root->balance() <= -2)
        rebalance_left(local_root);
    else if (local_root->balance() >= 2)
        rebalance_right(local_root);
}


void adjust_balance(AVLNode<Item_Type>*& node){
    node->update_left_height();
    node->update_right_height();
}

void replace_parent(AVLNode<Item_Type>*& old_root, AVLNode<Item_Type>*& local_root) {
    if (local_root->right != NULL) {
        replace_parent(old_root, local_root->right);
        adjust_balance(local_root);
        rebalance(local_root);
    }
    else {
        old_root->data = local_root->data;
        old_root = local_root;
        if (local_root->left != NULL){
            local_root = local_root->left;
            adjust_balance(local_root);
        }
        else
            local_root = NULL;
    }
}


bool insert(AVLNode<Item_Type>*& local_root, const Item_Type& item) {
    if (local_root == NULL) {
        local_root = new AVLNode<Item_Type>(item);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if (item < local_root->data) {
            bool return_value = insert(local_root->left, item);
            if (return_value){ //we have inserted the item
                local_root->update_left_height(); //left height might increase by 1

                if (local_root->balance() <= -2) // local root is now critically unbalanced
                    rebalance_left(local_root);
            }
            return return_value;
        }
        else if (local_root->data < item) {
            bool return_value = insert(local_root->right, item);

            if (return_value){
                local_root->update_right_height(); //right height might increase by 1

                if (local_root->balance() >= 2) // local root is now critically unbalanced
                    rebalance_right(local_root);
            }
            return return_value;
        }
        else
            return false; //item already exists
    }
}


void rebalance_left(AVLNode<Item_Type>*& local_root) {

    if (local_root->left->balance() > 0)  // See whether left-right-heavy
        rotate_left(local_root->left); // Perform left rotation

    // Finally rotate right
    rotate_right(local_root);
}

void rebalance_right(AVLNode<Item_Type>*& local_root) {

    if (local_root->right->balance() < 0)  // See whether right-left-heavy
        rotate_right(local_root->right); // Perform left rotation

    // Finally rotate right
    rotate_left(local_root);
}

void rotate_right(AVLNode<Item_Type>*& local_root) {
    AVLNode<Item_Type>* temp = local_root->left;
    local_root->left = temp->right;

    //adjust the balances
    local_root->update_left_height();

    temp->right = local_root;

    temp->update_right_height();

    local_root = temp;
}

void rotate_left(AVLNode<Item_Type>*& local_root) {
    AVLNode<Item_Type>* temp = local_root->right;
    local_root->right = temp->left;

    //adjust the balances
    local_root->update_right_height();

    temp->left = local_root;

    temp->update_left_height();

    local_root = temp;
}



 };

 #endif
```

This is the AVL_Node class

```
 #ifndef AVLNODE_H_
 #define AVLNODE_H_
 #include <sstream>



 template<typename Item_Type>
 struct AVLNode {


// Additional data field

int right_height;

int left_height;

AVLNode<Item_Type>* left;
AVLNode<Item_Type>* right;
Item_Type data;

// Constructor
AVLNode(const Item_Type& the_data, AVLNode<Item_Type>* left = NULL, AVLNode<Item_Type>* right = NULL) : data(the_data), left(left), right(right), right_height(0), left_height(0) {}

// Destructor (to avoid warning message)
virtual ~AVLNode() {}

int balance(){ return right_height - left_height; }
int height(){ 
    return right_height > left_height ? right_height : left_height; }

void update_right_height(){
    if (right != NULL)
        right_height = 1 + right->height();
    else
        right_height = 0;
}

void update_left_height(){
    if (left != NULL)
        left_height = 1 + left->height();
    else
        left_height = 0;
}

// to_string
virtual std::string to_string() const {
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "data : " << this->data;
    return os.str();
}
 }; // End AVLNode

 #endif
```

Finally, the class I created, the Folder class:

```
 #pragma once
 #include <string>
 #include "AVL_Tree.h"

 using namespace std;

 class Folder
 {
 private:
     string name;
     int size;

 public:
    Folder()
    {
    name = "";
    size = 0;
     }
Folder(string Name, int Size)
{
    name = Name;
    size = Size;
}
int getSize()
{
    return size;
}

string getName()
{
    return name;
}

void setSize(int Size)
{
    size = Size;
}

void setName(string Name)
{
    name = Name;
}
```

};

The error only occurs when I try to do

```
 AVL_Tree<Folder> folderTree;
```

it works for other types, such as string, int, char, etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated. As far as I know, we are not supposed to modify the instructor's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class Folder should be "comparable", it means the following code should compile `Folder a,b; bool result = (a<b);`

To achieve this, you can define the comparison operator withing your class

```
bool operator< (const Folder & other) const
{
    return size < other.size || (size == other.size && name < other.name);
}
```

Alternatively you can define a global comparison operator `bool operator< (const Folder & lhs, const Folder & rhs)`.